# How to use a Form::Select with a Pivot Table in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, forms, select, pivot-table

I try to use Form::select in Laravel 5.6, but when I went to the Edit Page, in the select, there are options with all the data of the object Model instead of a regular field.

I have a Game Model with a relationship ManyToMany with a Tag Model.

In my edit function from the Game Controller

```
public function edit($item)
{        
    $tags  = Tag::all();
    return view('megadmin.games.edit', compact('item', 'tags'));
}
```

In my Form Blade :

```
 {!! Form::select('tags', $tags, array_pluck($tags, 'id_tag','name'), ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
```

Here the result :

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVYze.png)

I just want a normal select/options with the data AND i want to retrieve the model Tag associated with the Game in the Game Form.

Thanks you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function edit($item)
{        
    $tags  = Tag::all();
    $goodTag = $item->tags()->first()->id; 
     //here assuming `$item` is your Game object and 
    //you have ManyToMany relation with tags with `tags` function in game model 
   //lots of assuming

    return view('megadmin.games.edit', compact('item', 'tags', 'goodTag));
}
```

View

```
 {!! Form::select('tags', array_pluck($tags,'name', 'id_tag'), $goodTag, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
```

Here is the laravel form select source code https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php#L393

and `array_pluck` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-pluck

Comment: It worked but there are still two problems :

1) I gave two Tags object in my Controller, fetched with the method Tag::all() and only one in my select

2) There a connexion between my Game and a Tag (I have a pivot Table game_tag) and the good Tag is not selectionned.

Comment: you have not mentioned about pivot table, update you question with pivot table

Comment: Still you have not updated with your relation but based on assumption i have updated answer. you can look it. the selected value is third parameter of ` Form::select(` and it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Form model binding, so you can do this:

In your Game model create a new method only for you Form Model Binding:

```
class Game extends Model
{
  use FormAccessible;

  public function tags()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
  }

  public function formTagsAttribute()
  {
    return $this->tags()->pluck('id_tag');
  }
}
```

In your Controller:

```
public function edit($item)
{        
    $tags  = Tag::pluck('name', 'id_tag');
    return view('megadmin.games.edit', compact('item', 'tags'));
}
```

In your view:

```
{!! Form::model($game, [$attributes]) !!}
    {!! Form::select('tags', $tags, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
     .
     .
     .
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```